# Django url file is calling the wrong function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call a function to write a file, but my Django url.py seems to be calling the markdown function. When you press the submit button on the form in the HTML, you get an error that throws at the line "if query["q"] in entries:"

HTML

```
<h1>New Page</h1>


<form action="{% url 'newPage'}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="t" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="10" name="c" placeholder="Markdown content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def markdown(request, entry):
    pathOfFile = "entries/" + entry + ".md"
    entries = util.list_entries()
    query = request.POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        if query["q"] in entries:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                "html_markdown": markdown2.markdown_path("entries/"+query["q"]+".md")
            })
        else:
            searchResults = []
            if query["q"] in entries:
                for i in entries:
                    if query["q"] in i:
                        searchResults.append(i)
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                    "searchResults": searchResults

                })
            else:
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
    else: 
        if (entry in entries):
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                "html_markdown": markdown2.markdown_path(pathOfFile)
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

def newPage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.POST
        title = query["t"]
        content = query["c"]
        util.save_entry(title, content)
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/newPage.html")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"), 
    path("error", views.error, name="error"),
    path("newPage", views.newPage, name="newPage"),
    path("<str:entry>", views.markdown, name="entry")
```

Error thrown:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /{% url 'newPage'}
'q'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'newPage'%7D
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'q'
Exception Location: /home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/ansley/Desktop/wiki',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Sep 2021 00:35:25 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 76, in __getitem__
            list_ = super().__getitem__(key) …
```

▶ Local vars

```
During handling of the above exception ('q'), another exception occurred:
/home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
```

▶ Local vars

```
/home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
```

▶ Local vars

```
/home/ansley/Desktop/wiki/encyclopedia/views.py, line 19, in markdown
        if query["q"] in entries: …
```

▶ Local vars

```
/home/ansley/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) …
```

▶ Local vars

Comment: `you get an error`: What's the error? Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**. Also what happens if `entry` is `error` or `newPage` and you want to call the view `markdown`?

Comment: That's a good question. What's the best way to solve for that? I'm new to python/django so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing.

Comment: For starters the paths should be unambiguous. The best way to do that is to prefix them with a fixed path, such as `/markdown/<str:entry>` so that it is never confused with another URL. Your error is caused by a typo in `"{% url 'newPage'}"` (missing `%` before the closing bracket). This is apparent from the error message (`MultiValueDictKeyError at /{% url 'newPage'}`) that indicates it couldn't parse the template tag. Otherwise it would have said something like `MultiValueDictKeyError at /foobar`.

Comment: You don't seem to have `request.POST.get('q')`, as your inputs have `name='t'` and `name='c'`. Also, it seems that you `urls.py` file is not closed properly (but maybe you have not copied it entirely).